# SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, iframe, frontend

I have a website within which is called Iframe. So two different domains are Iframe and Website. I get this error "SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document." if I am set local storage inside the iframe.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, any info?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies and user-data have not been enabled.
see https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document/